# String cannot be converted to JSONArray Android

Tags: android, json

I am trying to extract the long url from Google URL api. Following is code snippet, I am trying to get on with:
`       StringBuilder url = new StringBuilder(URL);
        url.append(shortUrl);

```
    HttpGet get = new HttpGet(url.toString());
    HttpResponse r = client.execute(get);
    int status = r.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
    if(status == 200){
        HttpEntity e = r.getEntity();
        String data = EntityUtils.toString(e);

        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(data);
        JSONArray ja = jsonObj.getJSONArray("longUrl");

        JSONObject last = ja.getJSONObject(0);
        return last;
```

The function containing code returns a JSON object. In logcat, I am seeing an error `org.json.JSONException: Value http://www.google.com/ at longUrl of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray`

The code is receiving the full url (http://www.google.com) but I am doing something wrong with JSONArray.

Answer (score 0):

Try jsonObj.getString("longUrl") instead of jsonObj.getJSONArray("longUrl"), because "longUrl" is a String not an Array and of course, assign the result in a String instead of a JSONArray.

Comment: On a side note: This the response from Google API: `{
 "kind": "urlshortener#url",
 "id": "http://goo.gl/fbsS",
 "longUrl": "http://www.google.com/",
 "status": "OK"
}`